# What are the disadvantages of using NZC Optocoupler as switch

Tags: ac, opto-isolator, triac, zero-crossing

I've bought some MOC3023 to use with a triac for turning some home appliance on/off using an EPS8266.
The thing is.. every place that I search says that for on/off the best is a zero crossing detector optocoupler and tells about inrush current, but isn't this the same as putting the appliance on the wall socket? I mean, when you plug in your coffeemaker and turn it on, does it have a ZC detector?

That is the first question about the principle.

The second and more objective question is if I can use this MOC3023 to turn on a LED light bulb (and the coffeemaker) without many problems.

I know that if the first answer is maybe I can tell myself but either way is best to ask.

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: @brhans thanks for the edit! English is not my primary language and technical stuff is a little harder to describe than general.

Answer (score 0):

Then "on" signal happens, in worst case, at peak voltage, current changes suddenly. Shape of voltage  distorted. Higher frequencies may cause interferences. Filters should be applied.
Comparing to manual connect, triac is faster, dI/dt higher.
The second question answer is depends. Heat dissipation should be calculated. In common the chip designed to control triac.